# Play sounds in my application even though ringer is in silent mode

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, ringtone, android-audiomanager

I have an application and I need to block the ringtone and notification sounds/vibrations, and play a custom sound while the phone is in incoming call state.

The way I'm trying to do that is to set the ringer mode into silent mode, when my application starts:

```
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
```

It does mute the ringtone and notifcation sounds.

However, when I'm trying to play my custom sound when the phone is incoming call state, using the music stream:

```
MediaPlayer mp= MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.my_ringtone);
mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mp.setLooping(false);
mp.start();
```

It doesn't work on some devices (one of them is LG G2).

I'm sure there is a way to solve this issue, because other applications/games do manage to play sounds when the ringtone/notifications is in vibration mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about audioManager.setStreamVolume ? Doesn´t it work?

Answer (score 0):

So the another solution was you can play the ringtone here snippet given below

```
int volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
if(volume==0)
volume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, volume,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(ringTonePath));
if(ringtone!=null){
    ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    ringtone.play();
    isRinging = true;
}
```

`isRinging` set as flag if you want to programatically stop the playing or you can check the by `isPlaying()` of ringtone to stop playing.

Comment: But the line "audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);" will cancel the silent mode, so what's the point? or Am I missing something?

Comment: hey did you try the answer i posted? accept it if it works for you.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal your solution works for except AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT. thanks for that but i want play ringtone when phone is silent mode also